# VBA to find word documents and specified words in content and then list in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have multiple word documents in a folder.
What I really want is to list the document names and check whether these docs incude some specified words.

I create two word documents for example to explain.
There are two documents, `Doc A` and `Doc B`, in a folder.
[image: Doc A]
[image: Doc B]

1. I want to list the file name `Doc A` and `Doc B` in the excel column A.
2. After listing the doc name in column A, I want to check whether specified words "classification" and "Statistics" are in the docs.
3. If these specified words in the document, it will mark in the excel. Please see below picture for the result I want.
   [image: Results]

I provide the code in the following:

```
Option Explicit
Private xRow As Long

Sub Get_MAIN_File_Names()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim xDirect As String
    Dim xRootFolder As Folder
    Dim DrawingNumb As String
    Dim RevNumb As String
    Dim rootFolderStr As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    xRow = 0
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .Title = "Select Main File"
       .Show
       'PROCESS ROOT FOLDER
       If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
          xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
          Set xRootFolder = fso.GetFolder(xDirect)
          ProcessFolder fso, xRootFolder
       End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(fso As FileSystemObject, xFolder As Folder)
    Dim xFiles As Files
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xSubFolders As Folders
    Dim xSubFolder As Folder
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application
    Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = Dir(xFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
     With objWordApplication
       Set objWordDocument = .Documents.Open(FileName:=xFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)

    Set xFiles = xFolder.Files
    'Adding Column names
    Cells(1, "A").Value = "Document Name"
    Cells(1, "B").Value = "classification"
    Cells(1, "C").Value = "Statistics"    
    'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
    For Each xFile In xFiles

      'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME, this part may not add
       xFileName = xFile.Name

       Set Docs = objWordDocument.Content   
        With Docs.Find  
         .ClearFormatting
         .Text = "classification"
         Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        End With

        With Docs.Find  
         .ClearFormatting
         .Text = "Statistics"
         Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        End With

      'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xFileName

      'Below needs to add.
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = 
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 2) = 
      'Above needs to add.

       xRow = xRow + 1
      With objWordDocument
       .Close

  End With
    Next xFile
    Set xSubFolders = xFolder.SubFolders
    For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
        ProcessFolder fso, xSubFolder
    Next xSubFolder
End Sub
```

Based on above code, it fails.
I think the problem is `With Docs.Find.....`; however, I'm not really sure about it.
Moreover, I do not know how to do this part.

```
      'Below needs to add.
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = 
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 2) = 
      'Above needs to add.
```

Can any one help me edit the code?

Comment: Although I agree with @Ken White (What was the exact issue?), I did get triggered to test such code (out of interest as I'm no professional and wanted to test vba with word). A possibly solution to your troubles is below Peter Chen. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JvdV, Thank you. I'll check and test for the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you out, it does:

- Assume you got a activesheet setup with the three headers there
- Loop through .docx files in specified folder
- Checks wordrange for specified tekst
- Returns true or false and puts found or not found in appropriate cell

  ```
  Sub LoopWordDocs()

  Dim FLDR As String
  Dim wDoc As Word.Document
  Dim wRNG As Word.Range
  Dim LR As Long, COL As Long
  Dim WS As String
  Dim wAPP As Word.Application
  Dim WordWasNotRunning As Boolean

  On Error Resume Next
  Set wAPP = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If Err Then
      Set wAPP = New Word.Application
      WordWasNotRunning = True
  End If
  On Error GoTo Err_Handler

  WS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
  FLDR = "U:\Test\" 'Change directory accordingly
  aDoc = Dir(FLDR & "*.docx") 'Change docx to .doc if you need
  Do While aDoc <> ""
      Set wDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=FLDR & aDoc)
      LR = Sheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
      Sheets(WS).Cells(LR, 1) = aDoc
      Set wRNG = wDoc.Range
      For COL = 2 To 3 'It will loop through B1 and C1 to check if present in text
          With wRNG.Find
              .Text = Sheets(WS).Cells(1, COL).Text
              .MatchCase = False
              .MatchWholeWord = True
              If wRNG.Find.Execute = True Then
                  Sheets(WS).Cells(LR, COL) = "V" 'Change V to your liking
              Else
                  Sheets(WS).Cells(LR, COL) = "X" 'Change X to your liking
              End If
          End With
      Next COL
      wDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
      aDoc = Dir
  Loop
  Exit Sub

  Err_Handler:
  MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
  If WordWasNotRunning Then
      wAPP.Quit
  End If

  End Sub
  ```

**Note**: You'll have to turn on Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library for this to work